# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while creating a simple UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

While declaring a simple UIAlertView, with the following code, I get the above mentionned error on that line:

```
UIAlertView * alerteken =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Please enter the @mailinator.com email address you want to read:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok"];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide a list of button titles terminated with a "nil" at the end:

```
otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil
```

Comment: Also known as a "sentinel," to indicate the end of the list of args.